# misaligned raid partition in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, partitioning, raid, software-raid

I attached two identical hard drives to my linux machine. Then using gparted I formated the first 1024 mb at the beginning of each drive as linux swap space.

Then I went into system->administration->disk utility. In there I went to file->create->RAID array. I selected the remaining space in each of the two identical hard drives and created a striped raid array.

After the array was created, a warning message appeared. It said "The partition is misaligned by 522240 bytes. This may result in very poor performance. Repartitioning is suggested."

What do I do now? As far as I can tell, the partitions are identical.

Comment: What made you decide to put swap space on your RAID0 disks?  This sounds counter-intuitive if you want good stripe performance... and assumes you actually need swap in the first place which many systems today do NOT.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Apparently the gui does something wrong when it creates the raid array. The way I did it was to format the partitions in gparted. Then I went into the terminal and typed the following:

> mdadm --create /dev/md0 --chunk=4
>   --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1

I used this as a guide:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=408461

When I went back to the gui it didn't have the warning message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's saying that the partition is not aligned on a cylinder boundary. `fdisk -l` should show it, but I'm not sure.